# Codes for the derivative of a random polynomials

Tags: functions

Good day! Please, I need some help here, I used this codes

```
RandomPolynomial[degree_Integer?Positive, 
   distribution_: NormalDistribution[0, 1]] := 
  With[{functionbody = 
     Sum[RandomVariate@distribution #^(i), {i, 0, degree}]}, 
   functionbody &
   ];
randompol = RandomPolynomial[i]
randompol[x]
randompolys = Table[RandomPolynomial[i], {N}];
numrealroots = CountRoots[#[x], x] & /@ randompolys;
```

to generate and solve for the real roots of random polynomials, but I dont know how to formulate a code that expresses the derivative of the polynomials generated from the codes above so that I can compute for the critical points.? I just want to verify something..

Answer (score 2):

Using the generator in your post:

```
RandomPolynomial[degree_Integer?Positive, 
   distribution_: NormalDistribution[0, 1]] := 
  With[{functionbody = 
     Sum[RandomVariate@distribution #^(i), {i, 0, degree}]}, 
   functionbody &];
```

Generate some polys, and their derivatives:

```
degree = 3;
var = x;
number = 5;

polys = Table[RandomPolynomial[degree][var], {number}]
derivatives = D[#, var] & /@ polys

(*

{0.967135 +0.119646 x-0.713662 x^2+0.263793 x^3,
 0.0898667 +0.512745 x-0.251378 x^2+0.672878 x^3,
-0.627538+0.627618 x+0.712827 x^2-0.157089 x^3,
 0.151949 -0.0394938 x+1.35897 x^2+0.932498 x^3,
-0.603811+0.290199 x-1.35976 x^2+0.0775911 x^3}

{0.119646 - 1.42732 x + 0.791379 x^2, 
 0.512745 - 0.502756 x + 2.01864 x^2, 
 0.627618 + 1.42565 x - 0.471268 x^2,
-0.0394938 + 2.71793 x + 2.79749 x^2,
 0.290199 - 2.71952 x + 0.232773 x^2}

*)
```

Comment: Sir Rasher, what codes should be added to solve the generated derivatives then count its real roots?

Comment: @Jerwin: Look at the documentation for `Solve`, `Roots`, and `CountRoots`. This is not a mechanical-turk site for work-for-free code generation...showing effort and up/down-voting / accepting answers gets attention here, "do this for me", no matter how politely it's done, tends not to.